# Google Tag Manager Handling Arrays in the Data Layer

Tags: arrays, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm new to Google Tag Manager so this may be a simple question. I'm trying to report on an array of data on the dataLayer.  A user is associated to X number of groups so I would like to report on it.  I set up a variable in GTM called "groups".  How can I manipulate that into a report that is useful? Is it possible?

```
<script>
        dataLayer = [{
        "groups":[
            {"id":"1","name":"Group 1"},
            {"id":"2","name":"Group 2"},
            {"id":"3","name":"Group 3"},
            {"id":"4","name":"Group 4"},
            {"id":"5","name":"Group 5"}]
        }];
    </script>
```

Comment: You could loop through the array and concatenate the groups into a string, and save that into a custom dimension.

Comment: Will GA parse that comma delimited string list for me in a report? Or is that a manual step?

Comment: No, you would need to do all that yourself. So the string would look like: "group1|group3|group5" or "group3|group4", etc. and that's what would show up in your report.

Comment: Would pushing each item in the array into a custom dimension work? Then could it show up on a report by user and all his groups?  This seems like custom code to push values to a custom dimension, unless there's a way to do it in GTM?

Comment: If you want to push each group into their own custom dimension, then you would need as many CDs as you have groups (which could exhaust your quota if you don't have Premium), so, yes, it could work, although I wouldn't recommend it. You can do this through GTM as well, by sending each group into a DataLayer variable.

Comment: If you do it using the Data Layer, how can GA pick up on it to report on it?  Wouldn't you just need a custom dimension again?